# Vue CLI 3: Sourcemaps cannot be parsed by Chrome devtools

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I built my simple site using Vue UI (the ones that comes with Vue-CLI 3), and it created sourcemaps in the /dist folder.  I deploy these sourcemaps along with the production files.  When I load up my site, Chrome indicates it cannot parse the sourcemaps in Devtools.

```
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: https://www.thisisnotarealdomain.net/js/app.92ef018b.js.map
```

I have tried the following in vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        // modules: true,
        loaderOptions: {
            // pass options to sass-loader
            sass: {
                // @/ is an alias to src/
                // so this assumes you have a file named `src/scss/variables.scss`
                data: `@import "@/scss/_globals.scss";`
            }
        }
    },
    configureWebpack: {
        devtool: '#source-map'
    }
}
```

and

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        // modules: true,
        loaderOptions: {
            // pass options to sass-loader
            sass: {
                // @/ is an alias to src/
                // so this assumes you have a file named `src/scss/variables.scss`
                data: `@import "@/scss/_globals.scss";`
            }
        }
    },
    configureWebpack: {
        devtool: '#cheap-eval-source-map'
    }
}
```

But Chrome still complains and I cannot see my original source.

I found some articles on the Internet regarding Webpack and Chrome interaction with sourcemaps, but I cannot tell if the problem has been resolved.  Is there a problem with sourcemaps created by Vue UI?

Thanks.

Comment: Having the same issue.  Did you ever solve this?

Comment: No, it is still unresolved.  I have tried to ask this on the Vue forums in the distant past but nobody answered.

Comment: why are you using hash in devtool prop value?

Comment: The hash values are values I found in other internet pages over 2 years ago when I was looking for a solution.  Do you have a solution I should use?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution, also have the same issue?

Comment: @keziakoko: I have not found a solution.  I have tried asking in the Vue forums, but nobody answered either.